# Reading first 5 lines of a URL, then printing in reverse order

Tags: java, java-io

I want to write a simple program that reads the first five lines of a URL and then prints them out in reverse order, so it'd be line 5, line 4, line 3, line 2, line 1.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
public static void main(String[] arg) throws Exception {

    BufferedReader keyboard;
    String inputLine;

    keyboard = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.print("Please enter the name of a company (without spaces): ");
    System.out.flush();        /* Make sure the line is printed immediately. */
    inputLine = keyboard.readLine();

    URL u = new URL("http://www." + inputLine + ".com/");
    InputStream ins = u.openStream();

    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(ins);
    BufferedReader readURL = new BufferedReader(isr);
```

What would be the most elegant way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: WHy would you want to do this?
Often it contains html formatting, or java script, or css, not usually relevant information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take [Reading Directly from a URL](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html) as a initial example, since it is already an elegant piece of code and accomodate it to your needs. For example ...

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class DataURL {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL yahoo = new URL("http://www.yahoo.com/");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                yahoo.openStream()));

        String inputLine;

        int i=5; /* number lines */
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (i>0 && (inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(inputLine);
            i--;
        }   
        in.close();

        for (i=lines.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.println("Line " + i + ": " + lines.get(i));
        }   
    }   
}
```

This code simply reads the first five lines and then outputs them in reverse order.

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks. And != null just makes sure there are still lines to read?

Comment: Yes, exactly .. a URL with less than 5 lines would not fail with that `!=null`

Comment: I'm a bit confused about where in your code the actual lines from the URL are stored in the String inputLine. It takes place in the (inputLine = in.readLine()) portion of the while test? I thought the while loop just evaluates to a boolean...? Meaning, I didn't think you could actually execute the code to add a line from the URL to our string...

Comment: `(inputLine = in.readLine()) != null` is the same that (inputLine = in.readLine()); inputLine != null. First it assigns the value and then it tests.

Comment: Gotcha. So the while loop will only tests conditions that evaluate to true or false, but that doesn't mean you can't throw in other code to execute?

Comment: exactly. People tend to combine true/false eval with assigning vars.

Answer (score 1):

Read into array and call a reverse function on it or decremented loop.